# Country selection, when country is not listed

Tags: landing-page, homepage

While this might not 100% match the intent of this site, it was the closest match from Stackexchange sites.

So, if a web site (the "entrance" page) offers a choice (a list) of countries, with the text "Chose your country", but the users country is not listed, what should he do?

One example is http://www.samsung.com/countryselection.do

Addition: I ask this standing in the users position. I encounter a web site and it gives me the above page. What to do?

Another issue: What is "my" country? My current location? My permanent residence? The country of my citizenship? Something else?

Answer (score 2):

This is a good place to ask. It depends on how you want to handle it. If you had offices on each continent you could give them the names of the continents or geographical areas to pick. Or you could give a link to the head office or international headquarters.

If you want the actual name of the country from them you could have a text box where they could enter it.

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons for having country specific content; language and local information. One thing that's good about the samsung page is it lists what language the selection is in. A user whose country isn't listed can pick a nearby country that does have its language.

The second reason is for local content. If you don't have any local content for a country, then it makes sense that it isn't in the list, and the user should either select a nearby country, or go to the headquarters page.

Your best option is listing an "Other" option and explaining why their country wasn't listed and what options are available to them, and it's perfectly acceptable to do that in just one language.

Providing country-specific content and language is a huge positive step for a company, but you can't reach everyone equally. There are always people who drop into the "Other" category, and they deserve a short explanation and some options and maybe contact information so that in the future they could have their own content.